# send response data to login packet of GT06 GPS device to send more data to server

Tags: php, sockets, gps

I have a GPS tracker device.I have already set TCP/IP and port on GPS device to receive GPS data.I am using the following script to receive GPS data.I am able to read first login packet but in response my server has to reply to receive further data .I am using the below php socket script to read and write data ,but I am not able to receive other than terminal ID.Any help would be appereciated! Thanks in advance.Following is the script:

```
 <?php 

     $host    = "**.*.***.***";

     $port    = ****;

     $mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);


    socket_bind($mysock,$address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

    socket_listen($mysock, 5);

    $client = socket_accept($mysock); 

    $message = "7878050100002dc20d0a";

    // $message is the response data which i have to send from my server to 
    // gps device to receive further more detailed data.

   // $msg = hex2bin($message);

    $output = $msg;

    writeToFile('gprs.log', $output);

    $output = hex2bin(getCrc16($message));

    socket_write($client, $output);

    echo "Sent and Received data successfully";

    socket_close($client);

    socket_close($mysock);

    function getCrc16($pData){

    $crctab16 = array(0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 

    ...... 0X1EF1, 0X0F78,);

    $hexdata = pack('H*',$pData);

    $nLength = strlen($hexdata);

    $fcs = 0xFFFF;

    $pos = 0;

    while($nLength > 0){

    $fcs = ($fcs >> 8) ^ $crctab16[($fcs ^ ord($hexdata[$pos])) & 0xFF];

    $nLength--;

    $pos++;

    }

    return ~$fcs;

}

  function writeToFile($strFilename, $strText) { 

    if($fp = @fopen($strFilename,"w"))  { 

       $contents = fwrite($fp, $strText); 

       fclose($fp); 

       return true; 

      } else { 

      return false; 

   } 

 } 

?>
```

Note: I don't want to use OpenGTs,Window hosting,any other third party.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution for reading and saving gt06 gps device data in PHP.Thanks to @claytonmarinho script for gt06. Below is the link to script for others who are looking for solution reading data in php:
https://github.com/vgartner/gps-tracker/blob/master/server/script_gt06.php

Comment: for reading and saving gt06 gps, we need only the scrip gt06.php or the WHOLE  php project please?